# Variable was never mutated

Tags: swift

I've been following an app tutorial of making a simple temp conversion app,

I have these lines of code as shown below

```
    // get the users imput : c
    var celsius:Int = celsiusValue.text.toInt()!

    //formula : c to f
    // 5f = 9c + 160

    // output : f
    var fah:Int = ( 9 * celsius + 160 ) / 5

    print(fah)
```

I'm getting a couple of errors with it that I don't understand why it is,

> 'String' does not have a member named 'Int'

Which would mean Int is not able to use as there is no integer in the string shown?

> Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use
>   '!' or '?'?

I have changed the code to

```
var celsius:Int = celsiusValue.text!.toInt()!
```

As it shows to do in the error helper thing but it still gives me the same error that the

> Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use
>   '!' or '?'?

So now I'm confused with it, I've read other threads regarding the variable was never mutated but it hasn't seemed to help me with what's happening with it

Comment: please specify of what type `celsiusValue` is

Comment: this is the piece of code I think you asking for                                 @IBOutlet var celsiusValue: UITextField!

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment...

"variable was never mutated" is not a fatal error in Swift. It is more a guideline, and a very annoying one. Each time you create a new variable it will say that, because you haven't yet mutated it. Xcode wants you to write all non mutating stuff as constants with `let`.

Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
This is a very important one, and you can find thousands of questions about it on SO. Swift has optionals, meaning it can hold a value or it can hold nothing at all. It will then be nil. This can lead to errors and that is why you use the "!" and "?". If you declare or unwrap with a "!" the result will be handled like it wasn't an optional. It might still be nil, but it will not be checked for nil. If you want to keep it more fuzzy, use the "?" this way Xcode will keep warning you that you are working with an optional.

But much more on this and how to write code with optionals can be found through google/SO.

As for the String => Int. If I remember correctly , this only works with NSStrings. So make sure you get an NSString there. Else you will have to cast it to an NSString.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will crash if user input is not convertible into an `Int` (ex.: "foo")

You might prefer rewriting your code as follow:

```
if let celsius = celsiusValue.text.toInt() {

    //formula : c to f
    // 5f = 9c + 160

    // output : f

    let fah: Double = ( 9 * Double(celsius) + 160 ) / 5

    print(fah)

} else {
    // Handle Error
}
```

Notice I opted for `fah` as a `Double` ... just to handle more precision, not for reason specific to your question.

Notice also how in this case there is no need to use `var`. Similar situations are very common and encouraged in Swift (as in other languages).

Hope this helps